# rpy2-2.8.5 image not found error on Macbook

Tags: python, jupyter, rpy2

When I'm loading rpy2 in Jupyter Notebook using %load_ext rpy2.ipython I get this error message.

I'm using python 3.5.3 (from official site, not from anaconda) on macbook El Capitan. Rpy2 is installed via pip3.

I also tried to import rpy2 in python3 console. 
'import rpy2' didn't complain, but 'import rpy2.ipython' or 'import rpy2.robjects' gave me the same image not found error.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-6344af05b9f0> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic('load_ext rpy2.ipython')
      2 #this doesn't work now, somehow
      3 #f**k

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in magic(self, arg_s)
   2128         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2129         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2130         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2131 
   2132     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2049                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2050             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2051                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2052             return result
   2053 

<decorator-gen-63> in load_ext(self, module_str)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    186     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    187     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 188         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    189 
    190         if callable(arg):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/extension.py in load_ext(self, module_str)
     34         if not module_str:
     35             raise UsageError('Missing module name.')
---> 36         res = self.shell.extension_manager.load_extension(module_str)
     37 
     38         if res == 'already loaded':

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/extensions.py in load_extension(self, module_str)
     85             if module_str not in sys.modules:
     86                 with prepended_to_syspath(self.ipython_extension_dir):
---> 87                     mod = import_module(module_str)
     88                     if mod.__file__.startswith(self.ipython_extension_dir):
     89                         print(("Loading extensions from {dir} is deprecated. "

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    124                 break
    125             level += 1
--> 126     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    127 
    128 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _load_unlocked(spec)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py in exec_module(self, module)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .rmagic import load_ipython_extension

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.py in <module>()
     50 # numpy and rpy2 imports
     51 
---> 52 import rpy2.rinterface as ri
     53 import rpy2.robjects as ro
     54 import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpacks

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py in <module>()
     90 del(os)
     91 
---> 92 from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import (baseenv,
     93                                          emptyenv,
     94                                          endr,

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpcre.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-35m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: How was R installed ? Other reports of the same error message appear to be associated with anaconda installations.

Comment: My R was installed through CRAN. I used to have an anaconda R installation and the conda-installed rpy2 was able to load, but complained about not finding the packages since the .libPaths() is different from my CRAN-R .libPaths(). So I uninstalled anaconda, re-installed python and rpy2, and this error occured.

Comment: Same issue for me - did you ever resolve this?

Comment: No. I gave up eventually. Ended up using an docker image